# Can't create nested tab routes with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create nested tab routes using React Router, I had a similar question but did not get an exact answer, when I try to create nested tab routes I start having problems when the page is refreshed, that is, when the page is refreshed, the content is serving me, at the moment I am working with two files, Lesson.jsx and App.js. Inside the Lesson.jsx file, I eventually have a Lesson component and some Routers (this is due to the fact that I create a sidebar) then I import the Lesson component inside the App function which is in the App.js file, but when I click one of the sidebar links and I update the page, the content serves, for a clear understanding of the problem, in addition to the code, I want to additionally provide a picture

[image]

**App.js**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <ParallaxProvider>
            <div className="App">
                <Route path='/Lessons' render={() => <Lesson/>}/>
            </div>
        </ParallaxProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**Lesson.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Example";
import './css/activeLink.css'

const routes = [
    {
        path: "/",
        exact: true,
        sidebar: () => null,
        main: () => <h2>Home1</h2>
    },
    {
        path: "/bubblegum",
        sidebar: () => null,
        main: () => <Home />,
    },
    {
        path: "/shoelaces",
        sidebar: () => null,
        main: () => <h2>Shoelaces</h2>
    }
];

function Lesson() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
                <div className={"sidebar"}>
                    <ul style={{ listStyleType: "none", padding: 0 }}>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map((route, index) => (
                            <Route
                                key={index}
                                path={route.path}
                                exact={route.exact}
                                children={<route.sidebar />}
                            />

                        ))}
                    </Switch>
                </div>

                <div className={"sidebar_content"}>
                    <Switch>
                        {routes.map((route, index) => (
                            // Render more <Route>s with the same paths as
                            // above, but different components this time.
                            <Route
                                key={index}
                                path={route.path}
                                exact={route.exact}
                                children={<route.main />}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default Lesson;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove Lessons <Route path='/' render={() => }/>?
Or add /Lessons for each path in routes?

Comment: const routes = [
    {
        path: " /Lessons/bubblegum",
        sidebar: () => null,
        main: () => <Home />,
    },
];



<Link to="/Lessons/bubblegum">Bubblegum</Link>

Comment: Is this a clarifying question? Doesn't quite appear to be an answer or attempt to explain anything.